# Spring Cloud Stream App that is both sink and source

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Can I create Spring Boot Application which is Spring Cloud Stream App having both the bindings Sink and Source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an app would seat in the middle of a stream, and this is called a Processor in Spring Cloud Stream / DataFlow lingo.

See [this explanation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#__literal_source_literal_literal_sink_literal_and_literal_processor_literal) in the reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A processor will pass the message from inbound queue to outbound queue with some transformation based on the binding. A processor will not act as a sink or source. What is the requirement for having both source and sink in one app.